# LaunchWaitCondition failed. The expected number of EC2 instances were not initialized within the given time

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

The error message is:

> Stack named 'awseb-e-r3uhxvhyz7-stack' aborted operation. Current state: 'CREATE_FAILED' Reason: The following resource(s) failed to create: [AWSEBInstanceLaunchWaitCondition].

I am trying to use Multi-Container Docker in AWS Elastic Beanstalk.

Can someone help me to get rid of this error.Is it necessary to use more than one EC2 instance for using Multi-Container Docker in AWS Elastic Beanstalk?

Comment: I am having a similar issue, and so far, the only way I've been able to get it to work has been to downgrade to an older configuration. The one that works for me is "64bit Amazon Linux 2014.09 v1.0.9 running Docker 1.2.0."

Comment: Me too. No VPC. Single container setup works just fine.

Answer (score 12):

This sound kinda what your issue is:

> If you use Amazon VPC with Elastic Beanstalk, Amazon EC2 instances deployed in a private subnet cannot communicate directly with the Internet. Amazon EC2 instances must have Internet connectivity to communicate to Elastic Beanstalk that they were successfully launched. To provide EC2 instances in a private subnet with Internet connectivity, you must add a load balancer and NAT to the public subnet. You must create the appropriate routing rules for inbound and outbound traffic through the load balancer and NAT. You must also configure the default Amazon VPC security group to allow traffic from the Amazon EC2 instances to the NAT instance.

Source: [Amazon EC2 Instances Fail to Launch within the Wait Period](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/events.common.connectivity.html)

Answer (score 0):

I've fixed this. It looks the like IAM role created by default for the single docker EB deployment didn't contain the necessary ECS Policy (unconfirmed).

I followed the [instructions](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/create_deploy_docker_ecstutorial.html#create_deploy_docker_ecstutorial_role) to create a policy to add the role and everyhing worked.

Answer (score 0):

To note for future reference, I just had a similar issue. This same event log can occur when you're starting your elastic beanstalk in a private VPC with RouteTable.

If you forget to add a AWS::EC2::SubnetRouteTableAssociation to your stack, your EB will keep waiting for a status until it times out and launchwaitcondition fails to be created.

[AWS documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/vpc.html#services-vpc-private) points towards an [example](https://github.com/awsdocs/elastic-beanstalk-samples/blob/master/cfn-templates/vpc-private.yaml).